# How to Return Separate Sums of Columns if Initial Value in row is < or > 0 in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, case, row

I am trying to write a SQL query that will return unique rows of sums of shipped part numbers per customer depending on if the value is negative or positive. For example:

If we shipped 20 of part Z to customer A twice, and they returned 6 parts back to us, it would display:

```
+-----------------+-------------+---------+
| Customer_Number | Part_Number | Shipped |
+-----------------+-------------+---------+
| A               | Z           |      20 |
| A               | Z           |      20 |
| A               | Z           |      -6 |
+-----------------+-------------+---------+
```

After running query, expected results:

```
+-----------------+-------------+---------+
| Customer_Number | Part_Number | Shipped |
+-----------------+-------------+---------+
| A               | Z           |      40 |
| A               | Z           |      -6 |
+-----------------+-------------+---------+
```

The query I have come up with is:

```
SELECT 
    Customer_Number,
    Part_Number,
    CASE
        WHEN Ship_Quantity > 0 THEN SUM(Ship_Quantity)
        WHEN Ship_Quantity < 0 THEN SUM(Ship_Quantity)
    END
FROM Sales_Line
GROUP BY
    Customer_Number,
    Part_Number
```

But I get error:

> Column invalid. Must be a group by column: Ship_Quantity in SELECT
> LIST.

When I add the "Ship_Quantity" to my GROUP BY, it does not give accurate results:

Original Input:

```
+-----------------+---------------+---------+
| Customer_Number |  Part_Number  | Shipped |
+-----------------+---------------+---------+
| A080            | C76           | -11.0   |
| A080            | C76           | -1.0    |
| A080            | C76           | -2.0    |
| A080            | C76           | -1.0    |
| A080            | C76           | -1.0    |
| A080            | C76           | 21.0    |
| A080            | C76           | 79.0    |
| A080            | C76           | 1.0     |
| A080            | C76           | 11.0    |
| A080            | C76           | 99.0    |
| A045            | X150          | -6.0    |
| A045            | X150          | -1.0    |
| A045            | X150          | -11.0   |
| A045            | X150          | -2.0    |
| A045            | X150          | -1.0    |
| A045            | X150          | -1.0    |
| A045            | X150          | -1.0    |
| A045            | X150          | 373.0   |
| A045            | X150          | 12.0    |
| A045            | X150          | 1.0     |
| A045            | X150          | 300.0   |
| A045            | X150          | 146.0   |
| A045            | X150          | 150.0   |
| A045            | X150          | 150.0   |
| A045            | X150          | 200.0   |
| A045            | X150          | 150.0   |
| A045            | X150          | 150.0   |
+-----------------+---------------+---------+
```

After Query:

```
+-----------------+---------------+---------+
| Customer_Number |  Part_Number  | Shipped |
+-----------------+---------------+---------+
| A045            | X150          | 300.0   |
| A045            | X150          | 373.0   |
| A080            | C76           | -11.0   |
| A080            | C76           | -2.0    |
| A080            | C76           | -3.0    |
+-----------------+---------------+---------+
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: How about `<>0`, as `<0` or `>0` means that it is not zero? Sorry for unfamiliar with SQL.

Comment: @tailsparkrabbitear Same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function `SIGN()` in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT Customer_Number, Part_Number,
       SUM(Shipped) Shipped
FROM Sales_Line
GROUP BY Customer_Number, Part_Number, SIGN(Shipped)
```

If your database does not support the function `SIGN()` use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT Customer_Number, Part_Number,
       SUM(Shipped) Shipped
FROM Sales_Line
GROUP BY Customer_Number, Part_Number, 
         CASE WHEN Shipped < 0 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9caa7accc0c774bc4b0040c3abe716ed).

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for! Can I ask how I would then go about making the negatives an additional column? So for example, have all shipped amounts in a column, and all returned amounts in another

Comment: @legendaryxv2 check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=10e486792e97e71463b2207be3bd02dd